# PHP bitwise comparison returning wrong value

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I'm doing these comparisons to see what options are enabled but the PHP is returning wrong values. I'm exactly checking what banks were enabled by the user.

Próprio = 1
Itaú = 2
Bradesco = 4
Santander = 8
Caixa Econômica Federal = 16
HSBC = 32

When I load the data from MySQL, I've get 16, so only Caixa is turned on, but PHP says that Próprio and HSBC it turned on too. I've made other tests and I received the following results:

1 & 1 = true
1 & 2 = false
1 & 4 = false
1 & 8 = false
1 & 16 = true
1 & 32 = true

2 & 1 = false
2 & 2 = true
2 & 4 = false
2 & 8 = false
2 & 16 = false
2 & 32 = true

4 & 1 = false
4 & 2 = false
4 & 4 = true
4 & 8 = false
4 & 16 = false
4 & 32 = false

8 & 1 = false
8 & 2 = false
8 & 4 = false
8 & 8 = true
8 & 16 = false
8 & 32 = false

16 & 1 = true
16 & 2 = false
16 & 4 = false
16 & 8 = false
16 & 16 = true
16 & 32 = true

32 & 1 = true
32 & 2 = true
32 & 4 = false
32 & 8 = false
32 & 16 = true
32 & 32 = true

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong: http://codepad.org/Lr9TTAJe In which format do you save the data in the DB?

Comment: Please show us the actual code you are using.

Comment: Cant reproduce: `var_dump(1 & 32);
int(0)`. Whats the exact code you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try casting both values to `int` before the bitwise operator. It seems that `"1" & "16" = 1` while `"1" & "2" = 0`.

**EDIT:** The reason for this is that "If both the left-hand and right-hand parameters are strings, the bitwise operator will operate on the characters' ASCII values" as described in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

**EDIT 2:** A quick test running bitwise operations against values cast to strings seems to yield results consistent with yours:

```
"1" & "1" == true
"1" & "2" == false
"1" & "4" == false
"1" & "8" == false
"1" & "16" == true
"1" & "32" == true

"2" & "1" == false
"2" & "2" == true
"2" & "4" == false
"2" & "8" == false
"2" & "16" == false
"2" & "32" == true

"4" & "1" == false
"4" & "2" == false
"4" & "4" == true
"4" & "8" == false
"4" & "16" == false
"4" & "32" == false
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have already commented, what you present in your question is hard to reproduce and the results are to be questioned because following the rules/definition of bitwise comparison in PHP ([PHP bitwise comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)) there must/should be other results.

Keep in mind that there is a [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Put the bitwise operation into parenthesis to get your desired result:

```
(32 & 1)
```

As you did not shown any code I'm not totally sure if that is your problem.

**Edit**

As [Kaivosukeltaja pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888403/php-bitwise-comparison-returning-wrong-value/5888546#5888546): The bitwise operator works on integers. You might want to cast you variables / values to integers first to be on the safe side:

```
( (int) 32 & (int) 1 )
```

This example is superfluos just to make visible what I'm writing about.

Answer (score 0):

PHP acts strangely over what is `true` and `false`.

Try using `2 & 2 === 2` (`===` not `==`) and see if that works better.

Comment: Where is it acting strange? Every number different from zero will be `true` and `0` will be `false`.

Comment: With bit operators the loose comparison acts exactly, like its usually expected: `if ($bitmask & pow(2,$i)) { echo "$i-th Bit set"; }`